# Hide list of occupants in converse.js

Tags: javascript, converse.js

Is there any way or configuration through which we can hide the list of occupants programatically while showing chat view in converse.js

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this via configuration, however you can hide it via CSS or you can write a plugin that overrides `createOccupantsView` on `_converse.ChatRoomView`.

https://conversejs.org/docs/html/plugin_development.html